# Optimize number of workers for several gunicorn instances

Tags: configuration, supervisord, gunicorn

I'm configuring gunicorn (monitored by supervisord and behind an nginx frontend) and got a bit confused about the optimal number of processes to setup.

In the [documentation](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#configuration-file) it is clearly explained that:

```
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

My machine is a quad core so that should count for 9 workers.

But I want to run *several* applications, each one listening to a different port.

Should the count then be (truncated):

```
workers_per_application = int(workers / NUM_APPLICATIONS)
```

Or should each have the above number of workers?

I think this question actually applies not only to gunicorn but to every similar kind of listening server...

Comment: a 'gunicorn' tag does not yet exist on server fault?! How so? Please somebody with good rep. go create it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, the workers_per_application is more of a performance tweak to ensure your application *can* consume 100% of the CPU at any time.  It does not mean that it will.  You can configure all of your applications to have 9 workers... as long as you keep in mind that there is a potential that one application could be working on something very difficult which would cause another to lag/fail-to-respond in time.  The whole "cpu_count() * 2 + 1" thing is a suggestion, at-best... and you can add more to it... or less as you deem necessary.  I am not sure if the cpu_count() returns the number of physical processors... or the number of CPU cores.  A quad-core + hyper-threading might appear to be 8 cores which would translate as 17 processes... or it might only count as 1 ... translating as 3 processes.  Fiddle with it & see what happens.

You may want to set a hard-number for that if you want 2 applications to run equally well without seeing much lag caused by the other.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that "ensure your application can consume 100% of the CPU at any time" is actually... BAD if I want to keep some spare resources for a database and some async jobs, isn't it? On the other side is "1" too little and it can result in often-blocked gunicorn because of one intensive request?

Comment: most of the time... applications like that won't ever really hit the CPU very hard.  Tweaking it probably won't be necessary.  In highly-scaled environments where you are really trying to squeeze every last drop of power you can out of your hardware... options like that can make all the difference.